# Help with a theorem question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> **Theorem:** Let $x$ and $y$ be integers. If $\mathrm{3x}^2 + 5y\not\equiv0\pmod{7} $ then $x\not\equiv0\pmod{7} $ or $y\not\equiv0\pmod{7}$
>
> A) Write the contrapositive of the theorem
>
> B) Prove that the contrapositive of the theorem is true, and explain why this also proves that the theorem is true.

I have the contrapositive written down as follows...But I am not sure if its correct.

> If $\mathrm{3x}^2 + 5y\equiv0\pmod{7} $ then $x\equiv0\pmod{7} $ or $y\equiv0\pmod{7}$

How would I go above answering B? We've gone over direct and inductive proofs so I'm assuming we'd use one of those but I am kinda lost.

Answer (score 2):

What you have written is not quite the contrapositive, but the converse of the contrapositive.

Suppose we have some expression of the form $p \implies q$, where $p$ and $q$ are arbitrarily, falsifiable propositions. The contrapositive is 
\begin{align*}
\neg q \implies \neg p.
\end{align*}
In your above statement, you have
\begin{align*}
& p = 3x^2 + 5y \not\equiv 0 \ \text{(mod $7$)} \\
& q = x \not \equiv 0 \ \text{(mod $7$) or } y \neq 0 \ \text{(mod $7$)}.
\end{align*}
Negating both of these expressions (the latter draws on DeMorgan's law, i..e, that $\neg a \lor \neg b\equiv a \wedge b$: 
\begin{align*}
& \neg p = 3x^2 + 5y \equiv 0 \ \text{(mod $7$)} \\
& \neg q = x \equiv 0 \ \text{(mod $7$) and } y \equiv 0 \ \text{(mod $7$)} 
\end{align*}
The contrapositive is therefore: if $x \equiv 0 \ \text{(mod $7$) and } y \equiv 0 \ \text{(mod $7$)}$, then $3x^2 + 5y \equiv 0 \ \text{(mod $7$)}$.

As for part (b), the second part of the question should be fairly straightforward: the contrapositive of an implication is logically equivalent to the initial implication. There are several ways to prove this, though it is most often done via a truth table.

As for the strategy of the proof, here is a hint for any such proof. In establishing an implication of the form $p \implies q$, you assume your antecedent, $p$, and then prove your consequent, $q$, based on that. Your first antecedent is $p$, with consequent $q$, and your second antecedent is $\neg q$, with consequent $\neq q$. The result boils down to some simple number theory.

Comment: Could you clarify how I would prove the contrapositive of the theorem is true? Im confused on that part.

Comment: Start by assuming that $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ in mod $7$. What can you deduce about $3x^2$ and $5y$ in mod $7$? What can you deduce about their sum? Once you show that the sum is equivalent to $0$, you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Implication:

$P \implies Q$

contrapositive

$\neg Q \implies \neg P$

The proposition:

$(3x^2 + 5y \not\equiv 0\pmod 7) \implies (x\not\equiv 0\pmod 7 \text { or } y\not\equiv 0\pmod 7)$

$P$ is $(3x^2 + 5y \not\equiv 0\pmod 7)$

$Q$ is $(x\not\equiv 0\pmod 7 \text { or } y\not\equiv 0\pmod 7)$

Not P...$(3x^2 + 5y \equiv 0\pmod 7)$

What is not Q?  What happens to the conjuction or when we negate it?

$(x\equiv 0\pmod 7 \text { and } y\equiv 0\pmod 7)$

Comment: Thanks for the response. Im still a bit confused on how would I go about proving my contrapositive is true though for part B, could you clarify?

Comment: The contra-positive statement:  if $x\equiv 0\text { and }y \equiv 0 \pmod 7 $  then $3x^2 + 5y \equiv 0\pmod {7}.$   Which is true as $3\cdot 0^2 + 5\cdot 0 = 0.$  The meatier part of the question is understanding what the contraceptive means.  Try some sentences in plain language.  If we accept as true that "when it is raining, there are clouds in the sky."  The contra-positve statement would be  "If there are no clouds in the sky, it must not be raining."